# Prepositions: can we avoid them

Tags: prepositions

Example:

> The tasks this layer is responsible for are
>    meaningful to the business or necessary for
>    interaction with the application layers of
>    other systems.

Can we omit **for** in **responsible for**? Because **for** and **are** together sound very strange. Or this **for** is mandatory?

Comment: The text as a whole is a bit "strange / convoluted" - I'd prefer ***This layer** is responsible for **tasks which are** meaningful to the business or necessary for interaction with the application layers of other systems*, at the very least. That would certainly get you out of your problem, but *syntactically* what you've written is perfectly valid. It's just "awkward" because your starting position was badly chosen (the ***layer*** is the naturally important "subject", not the tasks it handles).

Comment: Only a person can be responsible for something. ***The task this layer executes or performs*** [etc.]

Comment: @Lambie: Not so - if you do an NGram for "this * is responsible for", you'll find that *the most common word* for the "blank" is in fact ***mechanism***. Not a person at all. And the next 3 are ***group, fact, process***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's fine. I still don't like it here. The layer executes or performs the task. There is no need to say "responsible for".

Comment: @Lambie: Well, yeah - I agree that the whole tone of the text is a bit "precious". And something like ***handles*** is much easier for the reader to handle than ***is responsible for***.

Comment: it's strange to read such comments because the author of this text fragment is American (and famous author of programming books) :-)

Comment: Programming books? An *American* who writes *programming* books? So this means his writing is, like, excellent?

Comment: OK, I understand... :) But English is native for him and usually persons who writes books have good experience with different editors, etc, so they know language and idioms and can build sentences better than usual peoples, IMHO. May be you are write and I should not take such texts as source of true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "for" is mandatory with "responsible". You can be (just plain) "responsible" without any preposition, but if there is another noun (or pronoun, or other noun-like object) after responsible, you need a preposition there to specify the relationship between that noun and "responsible".

The combination "... for are ..." doesn't sound bad to me in this context. If you really don't like it, you *could* reword the sentence like this:

> The tasks **for which** this layer is responsible are meaningful to the business or necessary for
>   interaction with the application layers of
>   other systems.

But, to me, it sounded fine the way it was. Either way, you've got a somewhat complicated sentence there.